# How do I send an email through SMTP?

Tags: php, email, smtp

I need to send an email to a new user and myself when they register an account. I need to know how to it send through my admin email instead of the weird email address that the GoDaddy server uses to send it.

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "privatekey";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    die ("reCAPTCHA was wrong, try again!");
  } else {
mysql_connect("host", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("database");

$hash = sha1(rand (0,1000) );
$name = $_POST['name'];
$bmonth = $_POST['month'];
$bday = $_POST['day'];
$byear = $_POST['year'];
$sq = $_POST['security_q'];
$sq_ans = sha1($_POST['security_q_ans']);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = sha1($_POST['pass']);

$insert_query = "INSERT INTO users (account_act_hash, name, bmonth, bday, byear, securityq, securityq_ans, email, password) VALUES ('$hash','$name','$bmonth','$bday','$byear','$sq','$sq_ans','$email','$pass')";
$insertion_result = mysql_query($insert_query);
if($insertion_result) {

$to = "my admin email";
$subject = "New account created";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$bmonth = $_POST['month'];
$bday = $_POST['day'];
$byear = $_POST['year'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$message = 'EMAIL

Here is the account info.

Name: $name
Birthday: $bmonth-$bday-$byear
Email: $email

Registration IP Address: $ip

'

$header = "A new account has been created.";
}

if($_POST){
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
}
  }
  ?>
<?php
$to2 = $_POST['email'];
$subject2 = "Activate Your Account";
$email2 = $_POST['email'];

$message2 = '
Thanks for registering an account!
Your account has been created and can be used when you activate your account by clicking the below link!

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Email: '.$email2.'
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Please click this link to activate your account:
https://www.mysite.com/activation.php?email='.$email2.'&account_act_hash='.$hash.'
';
if($_POST) {
mail($to2, $subject2, $message2);
}
?>
```

Comment: *"instead of the weird email address that the GoDaddy server uses"* --- That's most likely due to a malformed or missing `From` header, which seems to be the case here. Switching to an SMTP server won't fix the problem, not while using the present headers as they are.

Comment: You're also missing a closing `;` at the end of `Registration IP Address: $ip'`

Comment: You use proper headers. See the manual on `mail()` http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the [mail doc page](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mail.php) you need to specify from in the header:

```
// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
```

You are getting a _ weird email address_ because you have not specified who the email should be coming from.

You have a bunch of additional problems:

### [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

I'm assuming this is what you were trying to do

```
$message = <<<EMAIL

Here is the account info.

Name: $name
Birthday: $bmonth-$bday-$byear
Email: $email

Registration IP Address: $ip

EMAIL;
```

### MySQL

`mysql_*` functions are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), read the read box.

This will also lead to *don't trust user input*, [prepared statements](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) are going to be your friend.

### Misc

When using double quotes, use curly braces with your variables:

```
$foo = 'test';
echo "This a {$foo}!"; // This is a test!
```

In this case `die()`, is a very harsh way to end a script in terms of user experience.

Comment: This should be a good start. Sidenote: I don't know how to render heredoc in markdown correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Thanks a lot for the extra tips. I'm new to PHP coding so I don't know that much.